# Regex to find all matching statements

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string:

> put 1 in pot put 2 in pot put 3 in pot...

up to

> put n in pot

How can I use C# regex to obtain all put statements like:

> "put 1 in pot"
>   "put 2 in pot"
>   "put 3 in pot"
>   ...
>   "put n in pot"

for `n` statements?

Thanks

Comment: You should read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq before posting.

Answer (score 3):

I probably shouldn't answer this as your question shows no effort at all, but I think a possible regex would be:

```
string regex = @"put (?<number>\d+) in pot";
```

Then you can match using:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Put 1 in pot put 2 in pot", @"put (?<number>\d+) in pot", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

To find the actual number, you can use

```
int matchNumber = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["number"].Value);
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer, i am new to regex really and i tried few things, which did not work for me. i hope you can help me a little more. in this case if i was to get all statements which start with put and end with pot what will be regex. the input string could be "Insert into table(a,b) Values(1,2) Insert into table(a,b) Values(1,2)" and i want to capture all individual insert statements "Insert into table(a,b) Values(1,2)" 
p.s I have tried "put.*pot" as regex but it returned me the whole string as single match or "Insert.*Values" in this case.
Thanks once again

Comment: You need to go for the *shortest* match (`.*` is "greedy" in that is always goes for the longest match). The shortest match should be matched when you use `put.+?pot`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this

```
 var reg=@"put.*?(?=put|$)";
 List<string> puts=Regex.Matches(inp,reg,RegexOptions.Singleline)
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(x=>x.Value)
                        .ToList();
```

---

```
put.*?(?=put|$)
------ -------
|         |
|         |->checks if `.*?`(0 to many characters) is followed by `put` or `end` of the file
|->matches put followed by 0 to many characters
```

Comment: And this is when I begin to hate regular expressions and LINQ ;-)

Comment: Your answer works for my problem, would you mind explaining the regex please.